# Unable to rescind downvote after the question was edited while deleted

Tags: bug, voting, deleted-answers

I downvoted an answer as it was not a valid solution for the problem outlined in the question. The author deleted the answer a minute or so later.

While the answer was deleted the author edited and fixed the answer to match the requirement in the question and then undeleted the answer. I returned to the question over 5 minutes after my original downvote had been placed, so I was prevented from changing my vote. However, I should have been allowed the change the vote as the answer had been edited.

I had use my edit privileges to make a minor amendment to the answer, which then allowed me to change the vote.

This situation seems like an oversight in the voting logic.

For reference, [this was the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46954629/519413).

Comment: `This occurred over 5 minutes after my original downvote had been placed` It occurred 4 minutes after the answer was posted, so it couldn't have happened 5 minutes after you cast your vote, unless you voted before the answer was posted.  You just mean you didn't *notice* within 5 minutes of when you cast your vote.

Comment: Good point, my mistake. I returned to the question over 5 minutes after the vote was originally made would be more accurate. I'll amend it. The issue is still valid, however.